# How to begin with FFMpeg - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, ffmpeg

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me towards beginning with FFMpeg. What I mean by this is could you point me towards a tutorial firstly on how to download and compile it, and secondly how to install it into my xcode project and use the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Gas Preprocessor](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2009-October/076618.html) and [ffmpeg for iPhone](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/).  I can confirm that these work - I just used the ffmpeg library in a project a month ago.

Comment: thanks, but is it true that it cannot be used with an iphone app that will  be submitted to the app store?

Comment: You should be able to.  What would be preventing from doing that?  Just keep in mind that ffmpeg is licensed under LGPL so if you statically link your iphone app to it you'll need to release your source code (under some interpretations of the LGPL).

Comment: Hi,

I downloaded Gas Preprocessor and installed in usr/bin/ 
I downoaded ffmpeg executable on ffmpeg4iPhone. Try to run it but i have an error : "Bad CPU type in executable"
I follow instructions : 

"   
- 
- Download ffmpeg from the Downloads section and copy it to your device

- Set permissions: chmod 755 ffmpeg

-  Run ffmpeg: ./ffmpeg


"


Please, can someone explain me how to build ffmpeg library for amrv6 & amrv7?